# Select multiple columns into multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
UserID  | UserName  | 534 more columns -->
1       | John      | 534 more values  -->
```

I'm looking for this output from only about 78 of these columns:

```
Column  | Value 
UserID  | 1
UserName| John
+78 more rows
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called *unpivoting* and I like to use `apply`:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values ('UserId', t.UserId),
             ('UserName', t.UserName)
             . . .
     ) v(column, value);
```

Do note that this assumes that all the columns have the same type.

`apply` implements what is technically called a "lateral join".  There are other ways to implement this logic -- using `union all` or `unpivot`.

However, lateral joins are quite powerful and unpivoting is a good introduction to using them.

Comment: From your perspective is this approach better than just repeated union statements:

Comment: Or better yet, could i approach this by building a "Column" table with all the columns i want to select and utilize sys.tables and sys.columns?

Comment: I accepted as is, this works for what I need. I'll just have 78 value pairs. Thank you sir.